# how to pass hardcoded guid in postman body section

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, postman

I'm trying to pass 2 guid values to a .net api like below image
[image]

if i pass like above image i'm not getting the values in .net
like below image .. pls let me know the syntax to pass the hardcoded guid in postman

[image]

Comment: what error are you getting after parsing those GUID ? 
You can try to generate some GUID's online here https://guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx

Comment: Could you post the `AuthenciateModel` class? The ApplicationId and DistrictId might miss a pubic setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GUID data type in JSON, so you can't use it directly.

Instead, you can use your parameter's datatype as 'string' in your model.

Then:

**Solution 1**

Optionally, you can define your parameters as string, then convert them into GUID in your method:

```
public class AuthenticateModel 
{
    //...
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public string DistrictId { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

In your method:

```
public SecurityToken AuthenticateUser(AuthenticateModel authenticateModel)
{
    var applicationId = Guid.Parse(authenticateModel.ApplicationId);
    var districtId = Guid.Parse(authenticateModel.DistrictId);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You can create 2 new variables:

```
public class AuthenticateModel 
{
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public string DistrictId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore] //this is for Newtonsoft.Json
    [IgnoreDataMember] //this is for default JavaScriptSerializer class
    public Guid ApplicationGuid { get => Guid.Parse(ApplicationId); set => ApplicationId = value.ToString(); }

    [JsonIgnore] //this is for Newtonsoft.Json
    [IgnoreDataMember] //this is for default JavaScriptSerializer class
    public Guid DistrictGuid { get => Guid.Parse(DistrictId); set => DistrictId = value.ToString(); }
}
```

and then use it in your method:

```
public SecurityToken AuthenticateUser(AuthenticateModel authenticateModel)
{
    //...
    doSomething(authenticateModel.ApplicationGuid);
    doSomething(authenticateModel.DistrictGuid);
    //...
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Is it true that there is no guid type in json, but the .NET core model binder will convert the guid string to a Guid type.
There is no need to write this Guid conversion yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the static method `Guid.NewGuid()` instead of calling the default constructor. This should work:

```
var ApplicationId = Guid.NewGuid();
var DistrictId = Guid.NewGuid();
```